# windows phone application button content

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I've got incredibly weird problem. I'm making memo game app on windows phone. When I click 2 buttons and if they have the same content they should collapse. Problem is that even if they have the same content for example 1 it shows me that this statement is false! Like 1 was not equal 1.

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Memo : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private int points = 100;
    private string[] numbers={"a","a"};
    private Button selected_button;

    public Memo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        button1.Content = numbers[0];
        button2.Content = numbers[1];
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selected_button != null)
        {
            PageTitle.Text = "" + selected_button.Content + " " + button1.Content;
            if (selected_button.Content == button1.Content)
            {
                button1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                selected_button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                points += 3;
            }
            else
            {
                points -= 1;
                selected_button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            }

            selected_button = null;
            //PageTitle.Text = "" + points;
        }
        else
        {
            selected_button = button1;
            selected_button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selected_button != null)
        {
            PageTitle.Text = "" + selected_button.Content + " " + button2.Content;
            if (selected_button.Content == button2.Content)
            {
                button2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                selected_button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                points += 3;
            }
            else
            {
                points -= 1;
                selected_button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            }
            selected_button = null;
            //PageTitle.Text = "" + points;
        }
        else
        {
            selected_button = button2;
            selected_button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        button11.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Please help :)

Comment: 1) Place breakpoint on `if (selected_button.Content == button1.Content)` 2) debug 3) on hit, `select selected_button.Content`, right click on it, select "quick watch" (NOT "add quick watch") 4) In the new window, examine the type of Content in the far right hand column.  You will likely find that your string has been wrapped in a different object, and two instances of that same object wrapped around a string do not consider themselves equivalent.  Use Tag to store strings used for equivalency checks. Or better, use MVVM.

Comment: What is button.Content? Which kind of object?